# How to inject datastore in `RoomDatabase()` abstract class?

Tags: android, android-room, dagger-hilt, android-jetpack-datastore

A little bit of background about my setup.

I have a JSON file used to pre-populate the room database on app start-up.

The data is versioned and any time I push new app updates with updated JSON data, the old data from Room has to be cleared and new data is to be used to populate the database.

For the purposes of maintaining the current data version in the room database, data preferences are used.

---

---

The preference datastore is accessed using `Context.datastore`.

I am changing my code everywhere to inject the data store instead of using a top file-level instance for testing.

Reference - https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/datastore-and-dependency-injection-ea32b95704e3

How do I inject the Preference Datastore created using Hilt in this class?

**Complete Room database pre-population code**

```
@Database(
    version = 1,
    entities = [
        Category::class,
    ],
    exportSchema = true,
)
@TypeConverters(
    CategoryConverter::class,
)
abstract class MyRoomDatabase : RoomDatabase() {
    abstract fun categoryDao(): CategoryDao

    companion object {
        @Volatile
        private var INSTANCE: MyRoomDatabase? = null

        fun getDatabase(
            context: Context,
        ): MyRoomDatabase {
            val tempInstance = INSTANCE
            if (tempInstance.isNotNull()) {
                return tempInstance
            }
            synchronized(
                lock = this,
            ) {
                val callback: Callback = object : Callback() {
                    override fun onCreate(
                        db: SupportSQLiteDatabase,
                    ) {
                        // do something after database has been created
                    }

                    override fun onOpen(
                        db: SupportSQLiteDatabase,
                    ) {
                        // do something every time database is open
                        Executors
                            .newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor()
                            .execute {
                                populateInitialData(
                                    context = context,
                                )
                            }
                    }
                }

                val instance = Room
                    .databaseBuilder(
                        context = context.applicationContext,
                        klass = MyRoomDatabase::class.java,
                        name = "finance_manager_database",
                    )
                    .addCallback(
                        callback = callback,
                    )
                    .build()
                INSTANCE = instance
                return instance
            }
        }

        private fun populateInitialData(
            context: Context,
        ) {
            val myRoomDatabase = getDatabase(
                context = context,
            )
            myRoomDatabase.runInTransaction {
                CoroutineScope(
                    context = Dispatchers.IO,
                ).launch {
                    val initialDatabaseData = readInitialDataFromAssets(
                        context = context,
                    ) ?: return@launch
                    launch {
                        populateCategoryData(
                            context = context,
                            myRoomDatabase = myRoomDatabase,
                            initialDatabaseData = initialDatabaseData,
                        )
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        private suspend fun populateCategoryData(
            context: Context,
            myRoomDatabase: MyRoomDatabase,
            initialDatabaseData: InitialDatabaseData,
        ) {
            val categoryDao = myRoomDatabase.categoryDao()
            if (categoryDao.getAllCategoriesCount() == 0) {
                val categoriesData = initialDatabaseData.defaultCategories.categoriesData
                categoriesData.forEach {
                    categoryDao.insertCategories(
                        categories = it.categories.toTypedArray(),
                    )
                }
            } else {
                context.dataStore.data
                    .map { preferences ->
                        preferences[CATEGORY_DATA_VERSION_NUMBER] ?: 2
                    }
                    .collectLatest { categoryDataVersion ->
                        if (categoryDataVersion < initialDatabaseData.defaultCategories.versionNumber) {
                            val categoriesData =
                                initialDatabaseData.defaultCategories.categoriesData
                            categoriesData
                                .filter {
                                    it.versionNumber > categoryDataVersion
                                }
                                .forEach {
                                    categoryDao.insertCategories(
                                        categories = it.categories.toTypedArray(),
                                    )
                                }
                            context.dataStore.edit { preferences ->
                                preferences[CATEGORY_DATA_VERSION_NUMBER] =
                                    initialDatabaseData.defaultCategories.versionNumber
                            }
                        }
                    }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My repo link for complete code
https://github.com/Abhimanyu14/finance-manager